# Ansible install .dotfiles through Mathias installer

Tags: bash, shell, ansible, dotfiles

I am attempting to install the following files ([mathiasbynens dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles.git)) on a remote server using ansible.

Here is the roles/dotfiles/tasks/main.yml file contents:

```
---
 - name: Flag if dotfiles directory exists
   stat: path=/home/path/dotfiles
   register: dotfilesdirectory

 - name: Remove old dotfiles directory
   file: path=/home/path/dotfiles state=absent
   when: dotfilesdirectory.stat.exists
   register: olddirectoryremoved

 - name: Clone repository
   git: repo=https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles.git dest=/home/path/dotfiles
   when: not dotfilesdirectory.stat.exists or olddirectoryremoved|success
   register: repositorycloned

 - name: Instantiate dotfiles
   shell: source bootstrap.sh
   args:
    chdir: /home/path/dotfiles
    executable: /bin/bash
   when: repositorycloned|success
```

And I am getting the following output when running the playbook and using -vvvv:

```
fatal: [ready]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "bootstrap.sh", "delta": "0:00:00.003190", "end": "2016-04-17 12:25:22.480491", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "bootstrap.sh", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": "/home/path/dotfiles", "creates": null, "executable": "/bin/bash", "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 127, "start": "2016-04-17 12:25:22.477301", "stderr": "/bin/bash: bootstrap.sh: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  All I want to do is run the shell command of `source` with the argument of `bootstrap.sh` when I am in the dotfiles directory (i.e. `source /home/path/dotfiles/bootstrap.sh`).  Everything I try either causes the script to hang when it gets to the last task on the list, or to error out with the error message above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the content of bootstrap.sh? You don't want to source that file. You should execute it as follows

`./bootstrap.sh --force`

Or if you really need to source it (probably not as an Ansible task) you could do exactly as it says in the README.md file

`set -- -f; source bootstrap.sh`